# Can I use Hadoop with AWS4-HMAC-SHA256?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

My newly created bucket uses [AWS Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html). I'm trying to use it with Hadoop and getting the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception:
org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/' XML Error Message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported.
         Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
</Error>
```

There's no mention of this on the [Hadoop Amazon S3](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) page. Is Hadoop incompatible with S3 now or did I miss a configuration option?

I've tried adding `-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4` as suggested on the [suggested on the SDK page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html), no luck. I assume from that that Hadoop doesn't use the Amazon SDK.

FWIW I'm using Apache Spark, but it uses Hadoop.

EDIT: I found [this Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-480).

Comment: Did you try -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to get data with s3n which will not work. Switch to s3a and don't forget to include the endpoint:

```
hdfs dfs -Dfs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId=<access key ID> -Dfs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey=<secret acces key> -Dfs.s3a.endpoint=<s3 enpoint> -ls s3a://<bucket_name>/...
```

The endpoints you can find here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This question was 2 years ago, so I've lost the context of the question.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed. I also found many similar ones so I thought it's good that it has an answer so that it would help anyone who looks for it

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer, if you think the question is still valid after this time.